# Android - How to make a landscape layout on a fixed portrait screen?

Tags: android, android-layout

My application's orientation is fixed to portrait due to some functionalities that always in action.
I need to add to the main activity a fragment with a landscape orientation, so it's layout should be portrait, but rotated 90 degrees.

My problem is that a TextView won't fit the screen because it's width is longer than the screen's width. Also, rotating it (or anything else) won't work properly because the rotation is being done after it's being located.

Is there any library that can handle such thing? Or what can I do to handle that problem?

Comment: no. I think you should change the "functionalities that always in action" to not be always in action. Don't fight the android system, flow with it...

Comment: I can't make any changes on those functionalities. I have to make a one time fitting of a landscape layout on a portrait oriented screen...

Comment: so what is the "functionality" that is always in action? Probably based on the activity? Then use a separate activity for this one fragment?

Comment: I wish I could. I am working on one component in the app within a team.
My view needs to be on top a working camera fragment.

Comment: okay, so doing setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE); in onStart and putting the orientation back to what it was in onStop won't be acceptable?

Comment: No, because the fragment is half transparent and on top something that should always be visible as portrait.